# Matching boost:none in UTs

Tags: c++, googletest, implicit-conversion, googlemock

I have a public function:

```
virtual void foo(boost::optional<bar> p_param) = 0;
```

and a mock for it:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(boost::optional<bar>));
```

When I write an expect-call like that:

```
EXPECT_CALL(aMock, foo(boost::none));
```

I get an error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'testing::StrictMock<AMockClass>::gmock_foo(bar boost::detail::none_helper::* const&)'
```

with information:

```
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const none_t {aka int boost::detail::none_helper::* const}' to 'const testing::Matcher<boost::optional<bar> >&'
```

However, when expect-call's arg is wrapped with Eq matcher:

```
EXPECT_CALL(aMock, foo(Eq(boost::none)));
```

The code compiles just fine. What's the root cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach does not work because:

1. Macros `MOCK_[CONST]..._METHOD[0..9]()`  generates two functions in Mock class - one obvious - the implementation of mocked method and one called from EXPECT_CALL of name `gmock_MockedFunction` - in this case `gmock_foo`
2. such generated method expects as arguments `Matcher<T>` objects - in your case single `Matcher<boost::optional<bar>>`
3. `Matcher<T>` has two constructors - one explicit - so it will not be used in your case - and one implicit expecting value of type T.
4. To convert from T1 to T2 (in your case from `boost::none_t` to `Matcher<boost::optional<bar>>` -  compiler would need to use two user defined conversions - from `boost::none_t` to  `boost::optional<bar>`, then from `boost::optional<bar>` to `Matcher<boost::optional<bar>>` - both conversions (as constructors) exist - but C++ allows only to use one user-defined conversions in such list of  conversion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337455)
5. FYI gmock specializes Matcher for string types to allow implicit constructions from raw string:

See this

```
template <>
class Matcher<internal::string>
    : public internal::MatcherBase<internal::string> {
 public:
  Matcher() {}

  explicit Matcher(const MatcherInterface<internal::string>* impl)
      : internal::MatcherBase<internal::string>(impl) {}

  // Allows the user to write str instead of Eq(str) sometimes, where
  // str is a string object.
  Matcher(const internal::string& s);  // NOLINT

  // Allows the user to write "foo" instead of Eq("foo") sometimes.
  Matcher(const char* s);  // NOLINT
};
```

Then - why it works for Eq(boost::none) ?

1. `Eq(x)` (where x is of type X) is a function returning `::testing::internal::EqMatcher<X>` - in this case `internal::EqMatcher<boost::none_t>` - so this is type of object you are passing to `gmock_foo(Matcher<boost::optional<bar>>`
2. `::testing::internal::EqMatcher<X>` is convertible (via user defined implicit conversion operator) to `Matcher<Y>` where `Y` is any type you want - e.g. you can convert `Eq(8)` to `Matcher<std::string>` - to be on safe side of the Force: some std::enable_if(is_comparable) gmock should use...)
3. And yes - the rule of single user defined conversion is met - since this conversion operator is the only onve conversion used by compiler to cast from internal::EqMatcher to Matcher

---

I think it would be nice that gmock is aware of boost libraries and has some  specialization for it - as it has for std::string - so you can write EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo("Hello")) for functions expecting std::string. In the same way it could be specialization for Matcher> to allow writing as you expected in your question. Let ask gmock folks for it...

**[UPDATE]**

I raised this issue in [gmock forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=pl#!topic/googlemock/ach1g2rumjM) - no  enthusiasm so far... It could be expected that they do not want to have such strong relationship to non-standard library like boost. I will return to the subject when optional will be standard - now I see it is [experimental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)...