# Sequence of user-defined conversions in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm facing a problem with a sequence of user-defined conversions in C++.
Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    A(int);
};

struct B
{
    B(A);
};

struct C
{
    C(B);
};
```

The constructors are defined somewhere.
Now, the following statements work fine:

```
A(1);       // A <- int

B(1);       // B <- A <- int

C(A(1));    // C <- B <- A <- int
C(B(1));    // C <- B <- A <- int
C(B(A(1))); // C <- B <- A <- int
```

However, when I try to compile the following:

```
C(1);       // C <- B <- A <- int
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘C::C(int)’
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘B’
```

I know that such a construction is illegal in C++.
Nevertheless, my question is:

- How can I get around it? I'm looking for some **elegant** solution. The constructions as `C(B(A(1)))` are somewhat annoying.

---

For completeness, I found several related questions (e.g., [Why user-defined conversions are limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21337198)). However, none address my question.

Comment: In the words of spider man, [everybody only gets one (user defined conversion)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYZfNZbn0SU)

Comment: the number of possible conversions would grow exponentially with the number of types involved if this was allowed

Comment: As to the first question, it's not so much that things would break, but that code would be much harder to understand. If two user-defined conversions were allowed there would be **far more** possible conversion sequences, sometimes involving types that aren't directly seen in your code.

Comment: After some thought, I decided to simplify my question. Please see the update.

Comment: How about adding a constructor `C(int)`? If that is not an option you might be able to use make-style functions like `C make_C(int)`.

Comment: @nwp: I have already seen such a solution. The problem with this or with adding constructors is that they involve redundant code. I was hoping there was some trick that would allow constructions as `C(1)`.

Comment: Write a proposal that allows extended deduction guides like `C(int) -> C(B(A(int)));`. It would allow you to do what you want while not having the problem of creating huge slow complicated deduction trees.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, your first question is already answered.

As for a work around, assuming you don't want to add an A constructor to your C class, you can just bank on the one allowed implicit conversion:

```
C(B(1));
```

The following should also works:

```
C(A(1));
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. However, I do not find it too elegant.